# Background process in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, lambda

I have been facing issues with a simple C++ group project I am working on. I am trying to create a thread that does a background job while my UI and the main app is working perfectly fine. I tried to the same thing on a test file before and it worked fine, however doing it in the Qt Project doesn't works somehow. I do not have much idea about Qt for ref. Here's my code. I am trying to **update the progress bar repeatedly** till my app runs.

Here's my code for more over view

**test code**

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int getRamUsage() {
    MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;
    statex.dwLength = sizeof (statex);
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx (&statex);
    return statex.dwMemoryLoad;
}

void ramUsage() {
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "RAM usage: " << getRamUsage() << "%" << std::endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}

int main() {

    auto ramLoop = [=]() {
          while (true) {
              std::cout << "RAM usage: " << getRamUsage() << "%" << std::endl;
              Sleep(1000);
          }
      };

    std::thread t1(ramLoop);
    t1.join();
}
```

It works, But it doesn't in the Front Ended Qt one I mentioned. May I know any other ideas to make this work.

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "ramUsage.h"
#include <thread>
#include <windows.h>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    auto ramLoop = [=]() {
        while (true) {
            ui->ramBar->setValue(getRamUsage());
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    };

    std::thread t(ramLoop);
    t.join();
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**ramUsage.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "../ramUsage.h"

int getRamUsage() {
    MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;
    statex.dwLength = sizeof (statex);
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx (&statex);
    return statex.dwMemoryLoad;
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**ramUsage.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef RAMUSAGE_H
#define RAMUSAGE_H

int getRamUsage();

#endif // RAMUSAGE_H
```

I tried using QProcess and the basic threading options for windows which doesn't seem to work

Comment: Your code has race condition on UI element - this is why it doesn't work. Threads are hard - your task is simple and `QTimer` would do job nicely. Anyway when  you are using threads in Qt use of `QThread` is recommended, then default slot-signal connection will do job nicely.

Comment: Learn to use `QTimer` and you will not need threads nor processes.

Comment: GUI elements in [almost] all GUI frameworks are not allowed to be updated outside the main (GUI) thread. Qt isn't an exception.

Comment: @MarekR alright but I believe there will be multiple progress bars in the program that means do I have to use QThreads or I could just use QTimer and do not expect a laggy application?

Comment: Also you block your GUI thread by joining your worker thread.

Comment: Just use `QTImer`. Threads in your case are pure overkill, it doesn't meter `std::thread` or `QThread`.

Comment: @MarekR V.K, absolutely working, easy concept. Thanks for saving my time :)